# How do you prove the square root of a sum bound?

Tags: inequality

For $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, how do you prove the following bound:
$$\sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} | x_i |^{2} } \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{ | x_ i |^{2} }$$

Comment: Try squaring both sides. You'll get $\sum |x_i|^2$ plus some non-negative terms on the right hand side

Answer (score 1):

In general if $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq  0$, then $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\ge a^2+b^2$

We proceed by induction. The base case is trivial. Suppose that the claim holds for $n-1$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
(|x_1|+\dots |x_n|)^2&\geq |x_n|^2+(|x_1|+\dotsb+|x_{n-1}|)^2\\
&\geq|x_n|^2+|x_1|^2+\dotsb+|x_{n-1}|^2
\end{align}
$$
by the inductive hypothesis.